# How to fix ‘max=" " dynamical in script ’ error in PHP”?

Tags: jscript

php mysql

var strHtml11 = "rec_qty; ?>\" >

How to fix ‘max=" " dynamical in script ’ its not working error in PHP” ?

Comment: your question in didn't understand what you want ? can you share your full code?

Comment: max="<?php echo $stock;?>" its working in html ... but not working in <script> var strHtml11 = "<input name=\"weight[]\" onkeyup=\"calculate("+count+")\" id=\"weight_"+count+"\" type=\"number\" step=\"any\" max=\"<?php echo $dd=$r1->rec_qty; ?>\" required=\"required\" />"; </script>

Comment: you are using wrong syntax please wait...

Comment: working are not i have update my ans. please check

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
var strHtml11 = '<input name="weight[]" onkeyup="calculate(\'' + count + '\')" id="weight_"+count+" type="number" step="any" max="<?php echo $dd=$r1->rec_qty; ?>" required="required"/>';
```